# Toddler injured nose while playing

Tags: toddler

My question is very similar to this one - [My baby fell from the bed. Is there any problem?](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/7517/my-baby-fell-from-the-bed-is-there-any-problem)

My 18 months old son today injured his nose while playing, he was jumping up and down, lost balance, hit his nose. There was a small amount nose bleeding, and after that 10-20 seconds he was ok. He is actively playing again, and eating normally..

Now, I don't want to be that "parent" who takes their child to doctor for even small things, but this has me worried..He has done this before, but previously, he got injured on hand , lips etc., and not blood, just scrapes / minor cuts. I can clearly see what the problem is during those previous instances, but since it is nose this time, I am bit worried. Should I take him to doctor?

Comment: "Now, I don't want to be that "parent" who takes their child to doctor for even small things," -- doctors should be fine with parents who take their child in to see them even for 'small things'.  A tiny number of parents are too anxious and will visit the doctor frequently - multiple times a week.  Those parents need some better support.  Also, in England, "Choose Well" where to go.  Don't go to A&E for anything that's not an emergency.Here's one example of a local "Choose Well" campaign. http://www.choosewellglos.nhs.uk/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your case seems different from the question relating to a head injury after a fall - if your son just hit his nose.

A nose contains many small blood vessels and bleeds easily. While it might look like a massacre, usually there is no real harm done. Bleeding should stop after a short while like you said. (But be aware that any nose-picking at the itching scabs might re-open the wound, so don't panic!) A cold wet washcloth applied to the back of the neck might help stop the bleeding faster.

Some people are more prone to nose-bleeding and bleed easily after a punch, physical exercise or even spontaneously, some "never" bleed.

But be aware: **If you should notice *any other symptoms* that fit the description of a possible head / brain injury, see a doctor *immediately***. It's a good idea to make yourself familiar with these symptoms, because your child will most likely hurt himself more than once in the next years.

Comment: I was the worst with nosebleeds when I was younger. A *tap* on my nose would cause them, no exaggeration. I'd also get such heavy bleeding while sleeping that it'd wake me up!   Anyway, I would also suggest learning how to properly handle nosebleeds. I lost a lot of blood at times, but the worst of it was the nausea from tilting my head back (which is **wrong**) and it would drain into my stomach. Extra +1 if I could for the last line.

Comment: True. As a "platinum member of the nosebleed club" myself (runs in the family...) I very much agree that a post about proper handling wold be a good idea.

Answer (score 2):

Your question is indeed very similar, and the [same answers apply](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/7517/my-baby-fell-from-the-bed-is-there-any-problem).  But, to be honest, if he banged his nose a bit but nothing is obviously broken, there are no signs of concussion, he recovered within seconds and is acting normally etc, I wouldn't worry about it.

(Also, a [laceration](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/laceration) is a deep, open wound that will bleed heavily, and would be *much* worse than a bloody nose.  Perhaps you meant an [abrasion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abrasion_%28medical%29)?)

Comment: Yes, I meant small scrapes / minor cuts, will edit the question.. Thanks for pointing out.. As you might have guessed already, English is not my primary language :)