# My 7.5-month-old often falls off the couch or bed. Is this dangerous or normal behavior?

Tags: behavior, infant, health

My 7.5-month-old son has fallen quite a few times off the bed and couch in just the past month. He lands on the carpet, and fell down while asleep only once.

The people I live with are concerned about him having any head trauma. I can say my son is 28 inches in height and is taller than both, the bed and the couch. His reaction most of the times is a disappointed face that he has fallen and the other times he cries.

Personally, I believe in him being able to explore and discover trial and error, but the folks I stay with want me to hover over him every second of the day and make sure he doesn't bump or whack or hit his head.

**My question is him falling from the couch and bed normal?**

Comment: Fallen off when he was asleep, or when he was climbing around? Has he fallen on his head? What surface did he fall on - e.g. carpet? concrete? Are there abrasions or lumps or tenderness on the part he fell on? If he fell on his head, are there any symptoms of possible concussion e.g. confusion, abnormal sleepiness, vomiting? If he did fall on his head then best to take him to a doctor, to be sure he's ok - you can't mess about with head injuries.

Comment: Yes, this is normal for a baby in this age as it can not judge the height. This is why you should always watch it and place it on the floor such that it does not fall off somewhere.

Comment: No he has fallen on carpet everytime. And only once did he fall when he was asleep.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because obvious troll is obvious

Answer (score 5):

"Trial and error" isn't necessarily the same for an infant as for an older child -- they are completely unaware of the consequences of their actions and so the parents need to be there to protect them from more dangerous errors.

Head trauma from falls can be one of those. It isn't necessary to worry about *every single bump*, but head bumps do need to be taken seriously. ([See this answer to a similar question for a good overview of symptoms to watch out for](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/a/7519/4054) so you can know what falls to really worry about.) Taking precautions to *minimize* falls is a good idea.

A baby who is learning to crawl should not be on an elevated surface (couch, bed, stairs) while awake; instead, provide a open area on the floor for him to move around in. When he's able to roll over in his sleep, he shouldn't be sleeping on that elevated surface either.

Comment: +1 - "Personally i believe in him being able to explore and discover trial and error" doesn't really pertain well in situations like this. If there was a dangerous chemical under the sink, a "trial and error" approach would be incomprehensible. Although not directly applicable, the use of that reasoning for in infant and head injuries is also not advisable.

Answer (score 0):

Not much to say, just to the point:

The folks you stay with are absolutely right.
Let him explore the world, but **never** let him alone!
(especially when his environment is not 100% safe in many aspects)
Keep him away from dangerous things (*Electricity*, *Heat* (Oven/Cooker), *Water*, *Windows*, *Stairs*)
And always (try to) catch him when he falls (height doesn't matter).

They have **no fear** and will try the craziest things.